# How can I get the intensity for a specific break in R?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
myHist <- hist(myData)
```

With this I can run:

```
myHist$breaks
myHist$intensities
```

To see all my breaks and intensities, but I'm wondering if there is a way to see the intensity for a specific break?  For example say the above outputs the following:

```
[1] 0 1 2
```

and

```
[1] 0.258 0.068 0.114
```

How could I get the intensity for 2?

Comment: `myHist$intensities[myHist$breaks == 2]` maybe? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Yep, that is it.  If you put that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[` operator to subset your results. Illustrating using `iris`:

```
x <- hist(iris$Sepal.Length)

str(x)
List of 7
 $ breaks     : num [1:9] 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8
 $ counts     : int [1:8] 5 27 27 30 31 18 6 6
 $ intensities: num [1:8] 0.0667 0.36 0.36 0.4 0.4133 ...
 $ density    : num [1:8] 0.0667 0.36 0.36 0.4 0.4133 ...
 $ mids       : num [1:8] 4.25 4.75 5.25 5.75 6.25 6.75 7.25 7.75
 $ xname      : chr "iris$Sepal.Length"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Now extract the data for the second bin:

```
x$breaks[2:3]
[1] 4.5 5.0

x$intensities[2]
[1] 0.36
```

or equivalently, to select an intensity corresponding to a particular break, you might do:

```
x$intensities[x$breaks == 4.5]
[1] 0.36
```

---

Note that there is always one more break than bins, i.e. the breaks indicate the range around each bin.

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is if it is possible to get the intensity for `4.5` not index `2`.  I understand that these are the same value, but lets say I know all of the breaks before hand and I want to get the specific intensity for a given break.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I just added it to Andrie's answer, as it's only marginally different from what he did. Trying to avoid clutter. Go ahead and accept his answer...